# Python - Return List of Latest .Tar Files For Each Unique Name of Customer Inside the File Name

Tags: python

I have various tar files in a folder "supertar", labeled as:-

`esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar,
esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05202017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06012017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4`

How do I extract the latest .tar file name for each customer, such as Mona, Jackson, Jonah mentioned in their respective filename as per their date values (At the end in the File Name) so that I get a variable with values:

`esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4`

I have executed the following code so far:-

```
import sys
import os
import tarfile,sys
import tarfile
import re

names = os.listdir('/home/neel/Desktop/supertar')
def parse_date(name, offset=-10):
    try:
        date_str = name[offset:offset+8]
        return int(date_str[-4:] + date_str[:2] + date_str[2:4])
    except (IndexError, TypeError, ValueError):  # invalid file name
        return -1
sorted_list = [x[1] for x in sorted(((parse_date(l, -14), l) for l in names), reverse=True) if x[0] != -1]

print "The File Being Untarred is:", sorted_list[0] 

tar = tarfile.open("/home/neel/Desktop/supertar/"+sorted_list[0]) 
tar.extractall(path="/home/neel/Documents/tar-dump-es") # untar file here
tar.close()
a=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", sorted_list[0]).group(1)
b=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", sorted_list[0]).group(2)
c=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", sorted_list[0]).group(3)
s = a+'-'+b+'-'+c # s=Mona-AB-Test226,Jackson-HQ-112 etc.
print 'Logging Latest Customer Log For:',s
```

This code returns in **sorted_list** variable only the latest .tar for any one customer with the latest date. I have many customer names like **Mona-AB-Test226** etc., so how can I make this all encompassing so that I get the latest .tar file for each unique customer name(that is latest) from a directory and have it untarred on to my dump folder in the format mentioned above the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your file name, find the date.

```
file_date_str = my_file_name.split('-')[-2]
```

Second, get datetime object for comparison purpose.

```
import datetime
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(file_date_str, '%m%d%Y')
```

Do the comparison and save latest filename for one file.

```
name = file_name.split('-')[0].split('--')[1]. # Get Mona, Jackson, ...
try:
    (latest_date, _) = my_dict['name']. # _ has file name, which you don't want to compare.
    if date > latest_date:
        # If entry for this name exists,
        # Replace the info with latest date.
        my_dict['name'] = (date, file_name)
except KeyError:
    # No info for this name in dictionary.
    my_dict['name'] = (date, file_name)
```

Run all this code in a loop, for all the files. At the end you will have what you want in the dictionary `my_dict`. And don't forget initialization and minor debugging that might be required.